# Different landing pages for mobile and desktop via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

If a user hits the url example.com or www.example.com he should get redirected to a landing page. But this landing page supposed to be different for desktop and mobile. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. Here is my current code:

```
#Redirect example.com to www.example.com/home (only for **DESKTOP**)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/home" [R=302,L]

#Redirect example.com to www.example.com/mobile (only for **MOBILE**)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com\/home$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/mobile" [R=302,L]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you so much! I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, I would guess that they are case sensitive. Try something like this instead: "Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini"

If that doesn't work, try specifying each of those in a separate RewriteCond line. I haven't seen that syntax of combining them all in one line before, and I don't have access to my dev box at the moment to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. It seems to be unrelated to case sensitive. But thanks for your help.